# Python - Manipulate HTML in order to use printer

Tags: python, html, printing

I am programming an application in Python that, among other functions, will print PDF files via a Xerox printer.

I am facing two options right now:

**First one:** find a way to comunicate with the printer driver so I could easily send instructions to the printer and do whatever I wanted with it.

**Second one:** since the first one seems to be a bit tricky and I don't know any API for Python that does something like that, I had the idea of using the service that Xerox provides. Basically there is an IP address that redirects me to an administration page where I can get informations about the status of the printer and... an option to select files to print (and set the number of pages, the tray where the pages will exit, etc...).

I think the best way is to follow the second option, but I don't know if that's doable.

Basically I want to be able to change that webpage source code in order to change, for example the textboxes and in the end "press" the submit button.

I don't know if this is possible, but if it is, can anyone point me in the right path, please?

Or if you have another idea, I would like to hear it.

By now I only managed to get the page source code, I still don't know how to submit it after I change it.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.example.com'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: What browser are you using to view the source? Also, what Python libraries/modules are you using?

Comment: I'm using **Google Chrome** and the `requests` library.

Comment: Alright, give me a minute to write an answer/take some screenshots.

Comment: I think that you're looking for [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). Install from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize), or use `pip`.

Comment: Before I try @nivix zixer method I'll try and check `mechanize`, @mhawke. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Xerox has a Python API or library, your second option is the best choice.

When you visit the administration page and submit files for printing, try doing the following:

1. When you load the admin page, open Chromes developer tools (right click -> Inspect Element)
2. Open the "Network" tab in the developer console. [image]
3. Try submitting some files for printing through the online form. Watch the Network panel for any activity. If a new row appears, click on it and view the request data.
4. Try to replicate the request's query parameters and HEAD parameters with Python's requests.
   [image]

If you need any help replicating the exact request, feel free to start a new question with the request data and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't have access to the printer right now so I can't test it. Next week I'll try and post the results.

Comment: Well, during this past week I managed to l work with the printing module. I started analysing your answer when something poped in my head: "Why not trying to use Ubuntu terminal to print the files?" In 5 minutes I had the module implemented. This is to tell you that I ended up not fully trying this method but thanks anyways for your help. It seemed the right path to follow if I really needed to manipulate HTML.